# I accidentally uninstalled pip form python2.7, how should I install it back?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I uninstalled pip by mistake and my question is how I can install it back? I am using windows.
 C:>Python-2.7\python.exe -m pip uninstall  pip openpyxl

I wanted to uninstall openpyxl but I forgot to delete pip

Comment: please also mention your OS ?

Comment: edit your question farnaz or you're going to get your first negatives! your question should contain the os and command you have ran resulting the removal of pip.

Comment: When in doubt, reinstall: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing pip is a simple 2-step operation.

first, you have to get the [latest version of pip installer file](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

second, You have to run a `python get-pip.py` on the file you have downloaded.

the file you download in the first step is named `get-pip.py` and, when ran using python is going to download and install pip on your os.

and you can always read the [documentations](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).